# Calculate, simplify and expand exponents with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Can we somehow calculate $a^z$ where z is a complex number ?

Does normal exponent rules like :

$$a^b\cdot a^c=a^{b+c}$$

Still work when complex numbers are in the exponent ? For example, do these egalities are true ?

$$2^{4+2i}+2^{3+4i} = 2^{7+6i}$$
$$(2^{4+2i})^{3+4i}=4^{(4+2i)\:\cdot \:(3+4i)}$$

Comment: $a^b + a^c = a^{b+c}$ is not true over the reals (or the complexes). You are confusing this with $a^b \cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$.

Comment: oops sorry i edited

Answer (score 0):

in that case using $\omega$ seems useful which implies $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}}$ for specific $k \in \mathbb {R^+}$ and $i$ is of course imaginary numbers

and as this implies angular coordinates on complex numbers then over I think